# Confirmação de exclusão de registro com javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Bom dia, apesar de haver algumas perguntas falando no assunto, não encontrei a resposta adequada por isso posto aqui a minha dúvida: Tenho um botão de EXCLUIR com o seguinte código:

```
 <a href='javascript:void(0)' class="btn btn-danger link_exclusao" rel="
 <?=$condominio->id?>">Excluir</a>
```

que leva ao arquivo action_condominio.php com o seguinte código:

```
 // Verifica se foi solicitada a exclusão dos dados



 if ($acao == 'excluir'):
    // Exclui o registro do banco de dados
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM condominio WHERE id = :id';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $retorno = $stm->execute();

    if ($retorno):
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Registro excluído com sucesso, aguarde você está sendo redirecionado ...</div> ";
    else:
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Erro ao excluir registro!</div> ";
    endif;

    echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='3;URL=consulta_condominio.php'>";
endif;
?>
```

que utiliza o javascript:

```js
/* Atribui ao evento click do link de exclusão na página de consulta a função confirmaExclusao */
var linkExclusao = document.querySelectorAll(".link_exclusao");
if (linkExclusao != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < linkExclusao.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      var id = linkExclusao[i].getAttribute('rel');

      if (linkExclusao[i].addEventListener) {
        linkExclusao[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          confirmaExclusao(id);
        });
      } else if (linkExclusao[i].attachEvent) {
        linkExclusao[i].attachEvent("onclick", function() {
          confirmaExclusao(id);
        });
      }
    })(i);
  }
}


/* Função para exibir um alert confirmando a exclusão do registro*/
function confirmaExclusao(id){
    retorno = confirm("Deseja excluir esse Registro?")

    if (retorno){

        //Cria um formulário
        var formulario = document.createElement("form");
        formulario.action = "action_condominio.php";
        formulario.method = "post";

        // Cria os inputs e adiciona ao formulário
        var inputAcao = document.createElement("input");
        inputAcao.type = "hidden";
        inputAcao.value = "excluir";
        inputAcao.name = "acao";
        formulario.appendChild(inputAcao); 

        var inputId = document.createElement("input");
        inputId.type = "hidden";
        inputId.value = id;
        inputId.name = "id";
        formulario.appendChild(inputId);

        //Adiciona o formulário ao corpo do documento
        document.body.appendChild(formulario);

        //Envia o formulário
        formulario.submit();
    }
}
```

mas não está excluindo o registro.

Onde está errado?

Comment: Paulo que browsers queres suportar? Podias fazer isso com ajax sem precisar de `form.submit()`. Assim estás a carregar de novo a página quando fazes submit.

Comment: Sergio, bom dia ! Estou utilizando um exemplo que vi mas somente com um formulário, e funciona perfeitamente mas meu sistema está implementando diversos formulários, talvez esse seja o problema. Ele exclui corretamente no formulário de clientes mas nos outros não. Procurei todas as referências aos ID`s e não tem nada específico tipo id(cliente), creio que não está atualizando a variável. Vou tentar outras funções para ver se funciona. Abraço

Comment: Paulo eu posso sugerir uma resposta mas gostava de perceber mais sobre o problema para não estar a adivinhar o que podes ter ou não. Que browsers queres suportar?

Comment: estou utilizando o chrome, creio que a grande maioria usa ele mesmo.Testei agora mesmo no safari e dá o mesmo erro.

Comment: Você pode verificar se o ID está sendo impresso no atributo `rel`? Ocorre algum erro no JS? Você pode mostrar o que o Chrome informa sobre o erro no `console`? Como você está recebendo o ID no arquivo PHP? Você pode ver se o ID está chegando no PHP por meio de um `var_dump` ou `echo` ou `print`?

Comment: Tony, o ID sai assim: rel="<?=$condominio->id?>  e chega assim: echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='3;URL=consulta_condominio.php'>"; o erro no err.log era esse: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /...../public_html/seguros/action_residencial.php on line 63 nessa linha havia um erro de sintaxe: já corrigi e resolvi o problema criando um javascript para cada formulário com nome diferente. A função faz referência à um arquivo: action_condominio.php e nos outros formulários o ID não era encontrado. Abraço.

Comment: @PauloFernandoCé Já resolveu o problema? Marque a pergunta como resolvido.

Comment: Resolvida ! Não sei como marcá-la...